# How can you split an input to go into 2 different lists using a ;

Tags: python-3.x

Ive been given a problem where given two lists, returns the list of all the elements that occur multiple times in both lists. The returned list should be in ascending order, without duplicates. Your main program will allow the enter two lists of numbers on one line separated by a semicolon and end input with a blank line. For example

Lists: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3; 4 4 2 4 3 2 4 4 3 1 3

List1: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3

List 2: 4 4 2 4 3 2 4 4 3 1 3

The result for this example would be: [2, 3]

I have a majority of the programming working, its just that after implementing the first for loop in the calculator function, I get an error. 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3;'

It may be a possibility that due to my inexperience there is a syntax error somewhere. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

```
def calculator(userinput):
    marker = ":"

    for x in userinput:
        if x == ";":
            marker = ";" 
        elif marker != ";":  
            numlist1 = [int(x) for x in userinput]
        elif marker == ";":  numlist2
            numlist2 = [int(x) for x in userinput]
        else:
            pass

    for y in numlist1:
        list1 = numlist1.count(y)
        list2 = numlist2.count(y)
        if list1 > 1 and list2 > 1:
            if y not in multiples:
                multiples.append(int(y))
            else:
                continue

    multiples.sort()
    print(multiples)

while True:

    multiples = []

    userinput = input("Lists: ").split() # asks for first input from user
    if len(userinput) == 0:  # breaks if user inputs nothing
        break

    calculator(userinput)  # calls the calculator function
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Why not update your question with the output you see when you run your script?

Comment: What output would you expect from the input in your example?

Comment: @RedCricket hi sorry, I edited my original post. Didn't think to post it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want …

```
$ cat intersec_two_list.py
#!/bin/env python

import sys
import collections

def intersect_list(lst1, lst2):
    return sorted(list(set(lst1) & set(lst2)))

def find_mult(lst1, lst2):
    c1 = collections.Counter(lst1)
    mc1 = [mc[0] for mc in c1.items() if mc[1] > 1]
    c2 = collections.Counter(lst2)
    mc2 = [mc[0] for mc in c2.items() if mc[1] > 1]
    return intersect_list(mc1, mc2)

def main(l1,l2):
        print find_mult(l1,l2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        user_input = sys.argv[1:][0]
        [s1, s2] = user_input.split(';')
        s1 = s1.strip()
        s2 = s2.strip()
        l1 = s1.split(' ')
        l2 = s2.split(' ')
        main(l1,l2)
```

You would execute like so ...

```
$ ./intersec_two_list.py "1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3; 4 4 2 4 3 2 4 4 3 1 3"
['2', '3']
```

Here is some explanation of the code above:

```
def intersect_list(lst1, lst2):
    return sorted(list(set(lst1) & set(lst2)))
```

In this method I `set()` to remove duplications from the lists.

```
>>> list = [ 1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,6]
>>> set(list)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Then we use `&` like so `set(lst1) & set(lst2)` to get a intersection of the two sets then convert that back to a list with `list(set(lst1) & set(lst2))` and then we return a `sorted` list.

In this method …

```
def find_mult(lst1, lst2):
    c1 = collections.Counter(lst1)
    mc1 = [mc[0] for mc in c1.items() if mc[1] > 1]
    c2 = collections.Counter(lst2)
    mc2 = [mc[0] for mc in c2.items() if mc[1] > 1]
    return intersect_list(mc1, mc2)
```

… use make use of `Counter`'s. What a counter does is this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,6]
>>> Counter(list1)
>>> Counter({3: 4, 6: 3, 1: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1})
```

It counts the elements of a list. This way we can get rid of all the elements in out list that did not occur more than once like so:

```
mc1 = [mc[0] for mc in c1.items() if mc[1] > 1]
```

The above is list comprehension which a short had for this python code:

```
mc1 = []
for mc in c1.items():
    if mc[1] > 1:
        mc1.append(mc[0])
```

Then key to above code is `c1.items()`. `c1` is a collection and collections have a method `items()` which return a list of `(elem, cnt)` pairs from the collections.  So `if mc[1] > 1` means the element occurred more than once and `mc[0]` is the element.  We save these elements in a list called `mc1`.

We do the same process on `lst2`. We create collection, `c2` and create a list `mc2`.  Now we get the intersection of `mc1` and `mc2` and return that and BAM! your done.

Comment: I understand "elements that occur multiple times in both lists" as "elements that occur multiple times in the first list and multiple times in the second list".

Comment: Yeah "occur multiple times in each list" well does that mean "occur more than once in both lists" or is once enough since 1 can me considered a multiple :)

Comment: Yeah @Mr.T that is how the question is meant to be interpreted it. I should've been more specific when I wrote down the problem.